# spa сайт и поисковые боты яндекс

Tags: seo

Есть spa - сайт, как известно яндекс боты не выполняют JS, поэтому для каждой страницы у нас есть заранее отредеренные HTML версии сайта. Они доступны, если в адресе сайта указывать http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=..

Вопрос:
Какого типа ссылки указывать в sitemap? C этим параметром, или нет? Как тогда в поиске будет выглядеть?

в head я прописываю meta name="fragment" content="!"

И что делать с rel="canonical". Где его в итоге указывать?

Вот что пишет яндекс https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.html

Но там не очень понятно, мои вопросы не раскрываются